# how do I publish a watson assistant bot?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I've created a bot using Watson assistant, but the bot responds completely differently in their dashboard vs via the API.

is there some 'publish' step? MSLuis has something like that for managing the deploy process but I can't find anything here.

While it recongizes our custom intents - so there is something working - it doesn't work as a "dialog"

Comment: Can you elaborate on "responds completely differently". Is it ignoring previous question asked? Is it giving a literal different response?  Try adding `<? intents ?>` to the output text to see how it's scoring intents.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using a recent version of the API. if you are using an extremely old version date then it will respond differently.

Comment: To extend what Mitch above said, the IBM tooling will use the latest date (version) number so you need to use the same latest date (version) for the API call. Note: this is not the V1 or V2 number, but the "The current version is 2019-02-28."